# sbt new project creation : No SDK problem , downloading JDK fails

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sdk, sbt

I'm trying to start a new sbt project in IntelliJ IDEA following theses steps
[image]

[image]

as you see in JDK i have NO SDK in order to solve the problem I did
[image]
[image]

[image]
and then the installation fails
[image]

ps: I was trying to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/setting-up-spark-with-scala-development-environment-using-intellij-idea-b22644f73ef1

Comment: Why not to install JDK yourself (not via IntelliJ) and then point to the installation ("Add JDK")?

Comment: the Add JDK.. option doesn't work (when I select it nothing happens)

Comment: Because you haven't installed JDK firstly.